# Bootstrap 3 Moving Items Between Rows in Grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make my layout move items between rows and the grid system is doing my head in with this!

at medium and above i want it to look like this

```
+---+-------+
| A |   B   |
|   |-------+
|   | C | D |
+---+---+---+
```

then at a smaller resolution i want it like this

```
+-------+
|   C   |
+-------+
|   B   |
+-------+
| A | D |
+---+---+
```

I've been trying with some nested rows but am getting stuck with the concept of how they shift based on the different sizes (sm, md etc.)

Comment: first tip is to always work with smallest view first.

Comment: Some layouts work with push and pull classes. If you need to push a column into another position HORIZONTALLY then it works. Your layout can't do this with the css in bootstrap, you can do this in CSS with Flexbox and create a fallback for legacy browsers or use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the hidden and visible class.
Take a look at [.visible and .hidden](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) on getbootstrap.com

So, you can imagine to organize your content as you need in your HTML file like this :

```css
.cola { background:red; height:100px;}
.colb { background:grey; height:100px;}
.colc { background:green; height:100px;}
.cold { background:yellow; height:100px;}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row visible-md visible-lg"> <!-- visible only on medium and large devices -->
          
          <div class="col-md-6 cola">col A</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 row">
            <div class="col-md-12 colb">col B</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 colc">col C</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 cold">col D</div>
          </div>
                        
        </div><!-- end row -->
      
      <div class="row visible-xs visible-sm"> <!-- visible only on small and extra-small devices -->
          
          <div class="col-xs-12 colc">col C</div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 colb">col B</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 cola">col A</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 cold">col D</div>
                        
        </div><!-- end row -->
      
     </div><!-- end container -->
      
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
</body>
```

Comment: i was looking for something where i wouldn't have to load the content more than once.  however this is somewhat helpful.